# SSRS is month greater than number

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following code which is failing

```
=IIF(Parameters!yearFormat.Value="fiscalYear", 
"FISCAL YEAR: " & IIF(Month(NOW()) > 6, Year(NOW())+1, Year(NOW())), 
"NATURAL YEAR: " & Year(NOW()))
```

The error i get is `#error` and I also get this warning:

```
[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox23.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing strings with integers without a cast.

Try using `CStr()` to convert an integer to a string:

```
=IIF(Parameters!yearFormat.Value="fiscalYear", 
"FISCAL YEAR: " & IIF(Month(NOW()) > 6, CStr(Year(NOW())+1), CStr(Year(NOW()))), 
"NATURAL YEAR: " & CStr(Year(NOW())))
```